# Best way to avoid multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I have a view which determines the type of a transaction and whether it has been successful...

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_payment]
AS
SELECT t.*,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (ht.Status = '0')
                OR
                (ebt.TransactionId IS NOT NULL AND ebt.TransferDate IS NULL)
                OR
                (ppt.TransactionId IS NOT NULL AND PaymentStatus IS NULL) THEN 2
            WHEN 
                (ht.Status = 'A' OR (ht.Status = 'F' AND ht.ErrorCode NOT IN (501, 500)))
                OR
                (ebt.TransactionId IS NOT NULL AND ebt.TransferDate IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                (ppt.TransactionId IS NOT NULL AND ppt.PaymentStatus = 'Completed') THEN 1
            ELSE
                0
        END) AS Status,
        (CASE
            WHEN ebt.transactionid IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            WHEN ppt.transactionid IS NOT NULL THEN 2
            WHEN ht.transactionid IS NOT NULL THEN 3
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS PaymentMethodId
FROM
    tbl_transaction t
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_transaction_hsbc ht
ON 
    t.transactionid = ht.transactionid
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_transaction_bank_transfer ebt
ON 
    t.transactionid = ebt.transactionid
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_transaction_paypal ppt
ON 
    t.transactionid = ppt.transactionid
```

What is a good way to avoid having to look up the status without needing multiple left joins and a case statement?

I cannot use an indexed view because of the left joins.

The only alternative I can think of is storing a redundant status in the base transaction table.

When selecting successful transactions, almost 100% of the query is working out the status, and this won't scale to, say, 100 transaction types.

Comment: This is a common way to store multiple types when using an OR mapper. What about the differences in the transaction types? For example, a bank transfer has a GUID identifier for looking up and modifying a transaction from a web page.

Comment: I think it's good to keep a copy of the original response data in case of errors. In which case, storing my own system's value instead of deriving it on the fly is redundant.

Comment: My transaction primary key is a SQL Server identity column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better design would have a transactions table and a column indicating the type, instead of all these tables stacking up to store information that is slightly different but mostly the same. - [user1186](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)

It looks to me that status and type should be stored in the base table , not in derived tables. Status appears to me as a common attribute of all transactions.

I'd rather say that it's redundant (from pure theoretical perspective) to store it in derived tables. Type - yes, it may be considered redundant, but having it in the base table can help a lot: First of all, it can be used to enforce storing transaction specific data in particular detail table; secondly, it eliminates joins completely if you're interested only in common attributes regardless of how many payment methods you have.

No matter what PayPal, or HSBC have, it belongs to their system. You are storing data in your system. Transaction status in your system may be Approved, Declined, Failed, etc. PayPal may have "01" for Approved , and "R2" for declined, or whatever. It's the responsibility of the application to properly map PayPal response to your "Approved", not that database should know what error code 501 means for Prepaid Card. - [user2232](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2232/a1ex07)

When I build for multiple foreign systems like this, I would have a TransactionType table with a `ForeignSystemCode`, and a `SourceID` (the `SourceID` would come from another lookup table). PayPal's source would be SourceID 3, for instance, and in the FSC for PayPal's code it'd be '01'. Then my own Primary Key is what is in my Transaction table. - [user101326](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/101326/randolph-west)